# How to filter many value in same time?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search to filter 1 document and i use a loop to filer many documents. But now i want to filter many document in one request to optimize my script.

For the moment i have this query, and i'm using a "for" loop to filter by uuid.

```
for id in id_list:
    filter (id)

def filter(id): 

    result = requests.get(
            settings + '/data/_search?size=10000',
            json={
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": {
                            "terms": {
                                "id": id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_source": {
                    "exclude": ["type", "date"]
                }
            }
        )
```

I would like to do only one request to get all my document at once to optimize my code.

Comment: Is your calling code in python? What do you want to filter for? Can you do the filter in the query rather than the calling code? Can your code handle all the documents in ES?

Comment: Yes it's python but it's more an elascticsearch problem, i updated it anyway. aHochstein answer it too :) thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms query takes an array of arguments, see the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html) for an example.